# What is the use of systemutil in android?

Tags: android

I want to know the use of systemutil in android.

Like this:

```
String ringFile = sp.getString(SystemUtil.KEY_RING_TONE, null);
if(ringFile==null){
//No value, is null, do not play the bell
ringTone=null;
```

What is the use of systemutil in android?

Comment: There is no such utility class in Android called SystemUtil.

Comment: Check from where you copied the code.